# Filter out unique objects and returning the whole object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have results which are structured like this, with duplicates:

```js
result: { 
  {id: "6766", name: "Bob", tickets: 95, lastWon: "2019-08-23T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
  {id: "3334", name: "Anne", tickets: 177, lastWon: "2019-06-21T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
  {id: "3019", name: "Carl", tickets: 221, lastWon: "2019-05-24T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
  {id: "6766", name: "Bob", tickets: 95, lastWon: "2019-08-23T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
  {id: "3334", name: "Anne", tickets: 177, lastWon: "2019-06-21T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
  {id: "3019", name: "Carl", tickets: 221, lastWon: "2019-05-24T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
}
```

How can I use React to filter out the duplicated so it only outputs:

```js
result: { 
  {id: "6766", name: "Bob", tickets: 95, lastWon: "2019-08-23T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
  {id: "3334", name: "Anne", tickets: 177, lastWon: "2019-06-21T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
  {id: "3019", name: "Carl", tickets: 221, lastWon: "2019-05-24T00:00:00", departmentId: "28"}
}
```

Comment: I think `result` is an array, not an object like in your example because it lacks the property's name. Please precise your goal if it should be an object or array.

Comment: The snippet editor has four parts. Each has a specific task. Pasting JavaScript in the HTML section doesn't make any sense ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Using filter...

```
data.filter((item, index) => data.indexOf(item) === index);
```

This works because indexOf will return the first instance that an element exists, so any duplicates would not pass the filter condition.

Comment: You probably meant `data.indexOf(item)`.

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately this does not work. `indexOf` does not work when the `item` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

We do know `Set` Object is useful to keep unique items but we may have several fields in the object and `Set` can not filter unique object arrays.

We can use `JSON.stringify` to populate plain text from the object and put it in `Set`, then it's UNIQUE. :)

The code snippet below.

```
        let uniqueReferrals = new Set();

        referrals.forEach((el) => {
          uniqueReferrals.add(JSON.stringify(el));
        });

        uniqueReferrals = Array.from(uniqueReferrals);
        uniqueReferrals = uniqueReferrals.map((el) => {
          return JSON.parse(el);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array, I usually like to convert it to map/object to ensure uniqueness (as opposed to using Set or other). You could do the below:

```js
   result.reduce((map, val)=>{
        return {
             ...map,
             [val.id] : val
        }
    }, {})
```